# Simply setting a DEFAULT vs setting a CONSTRAINT on a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value

I'm almost new at SQL Server programming. Today I have found these two different strategies to define a default value for a column, I would ask the experts the difference between them.

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data] 
(
    [RecDataW] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Snippet #1:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatiSetup] 
    ADD DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RecDataW]
GO
```

Snippet #2:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatiSetup] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_DatiSetup_RecDataW] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RecDataW]
GO
```

Comment: They are the same thing - `DEFAULT` is a `CONSTRAINT`, the only difference between the two is that you have explicitly named the constraint `DF_DatiSetup_RecDataW` in the second one, but not the first.  You could also shortcut this by doing `CREATE TABLE dbo.Data (RecDataW DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE())`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is assigning an explicit, known name. The form

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatiSetup] 
    ADD DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RecDataW]
```

will create a default with a name, but the name is system generated, and will be different in each environment the script is deployed to. (Dev, test, UAT, staging, production, Bob's desktop, etc.) If you need to alter the default, this can be a problem.

The form

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DatiSetup] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_DatiSetup_RecDataW] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RecDataW]
```

explicitly names the default, so that the name is uniform in all environments. So one has a way of referencing, in all environments, in a repeatable way, the default if it needs to be dropped, altered, etc.

The standard of the places I have worked for the last few years is to **always** name constraints. [Sometimes that's the standard, because I have the authority to make it the standard. Sometimes someone else has already made it the standard.]

Also, there are ways of developing and deploying SQL where the first system generated name is used on subsequent environments. The tools used explicitly name the constraint downstream to match. Red Gate Sql Source and Sql Compare can do this. Even so, name all the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Like Siyual said in his comment, these are the same thing. A default value is creating a constraint for you. Creating a constraint with a default value is you creating the constraint that you name. You can find [documentation on default constraints here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns).

Answer (score 0):

The constraint will allow you to name whereas the default will create the name randomly for you. A good example for this is when you are working in a multi tenant environment. If you have an application that has many copies of a database (One per tenant for example) it will be hard to make changes/maintain/deploy in the future if the defaults are not explicitly named